# Adding curveEaseIn to Swift Animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimation-curve

I have an image that rotates but it stops abruptly.  I'd like to add curveEaseOut to make it stop smoother, but when I add the animations: .curveEaseOut, I get an error.

```
func rotateRight () {
    let rotation = 90.0
    let transform = imageGearRight.transform
    let rotated = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(rotation))
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: .curveEaseOut) {
        self.imageGearRight.transform = rotated
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error:
Type '() -> Void' has no member 'curveEaseOut'

I've also tried this code, but I get an error also:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: UIViewAnimationCurve.easeOut) {
        self.imageGearRight.transform = rotated
    }
```

Not sure what I am missing.  Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to specify `.curveEaseOut` you have to use a `UIView` method that takes options:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
               delay: 0,
               options: [ .curveEaseOut ],
               animations: {
                   self.imageGearRight.transform = rotated
               },
               completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  You've been a great help!