# Is there an equivalent of FastOutSlowInInterpolator for iOS?

Tags: android, ios, interpolation, androidx

Is there an equivalent of [FastOutSlowInInterpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/animation/FastOutSlowInInterpolator.html) for iOS? I've recently got my hands on AndroidX and really like this interpolator. I've found the [source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:interpolator/interpolator/src/main/java/androidx/interpolator/view/animation/FastOutSlowInInterpolator.java?q=FastOutSlowInInterpolator) for it too but have no idea how to convert it to iOS implementation.

Comment: May be [curveEaseOut](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/animationoptions/1622656-curveeaseout) is what you are looking for?
You can use [UIView animate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622451-animate)

Comment: how can I use this with `UIViewPropertyAnimator`?

Comment: How about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488066/adding-curveeasein-to-swift-animation)

Comment: Can you put an example of the animation you need? (a gif maybe)

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Look for fast out slow in animation on https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-interpolators-a-visual-guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `UIViewPropertyAnimator` the curve that you need is [.easeInOut](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/animationcurve/easeinout), and you can pass it as `curve` parameter when you create your animator:

```swift
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.4, curve: .easeInOut) {
    // Animations
}
```

If you are not happy with this system curve, you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40363603/6791677) and use [this handy website](https://cubic-bezier.com/#.4,0,.2,1) to replicate `FastOutSlowInInterpolator`'s control points.

As [FastOutSlowInInterpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/animation/FastOutSlowInInterpolator.html) documentation states:

> Interpolator corresponding to `fast_out_slow_in`. Uses a lookup table
> for the Bezier curve from (0,0) to (1,1) with control points: P0 (0,
> 0) **P1 (0.4, 0) P2 (0.2, 1.0)** P3 (1.0, 1.0)

So, in your particular case you are looking for something like this:

```swift
let timingParameters = UICubicTimingParameters(
    controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.4, y: 0),
    controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.2, y: 1)
)
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.4, timingParameters: timingParameters)
```

or this:

```swift
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(
    duration: 0.4,
    controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.4, y: 0),
    controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.2, y: 1)
) {
    // Animations
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## SwiftUI

In SwiftUI you can animate almost any change with `.animate` modifier and it accepts the curve as the argument. I think `.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 30, damping: 20)` is the curve that you are looking for (the bottom one).

#### Examples

[image: Demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isLeading = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SpacedCircle(isLeading: $isLeading)
                .animation(.linear)

            SpacedCircle(isLeading: $isLeading)
                .animation(.easeIn)

            SpacedCircle(isLeading: $isLeading)
                .animation(.easeOut)

            SpacedCircle(isLeading: $isLeading)
                .animation(.easeInOut)

            SpacedCircle(isLeading: $isLeading)
                .animation(.interactiveSpring(response: 0.27, dampingFraction: 0.5, blendDuration: 0.2))

            SpacedCircle(isLeading: $isLeading)
                .animation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 30, damping: 20))

            Button("Toggle") { isLeading.toggle() }
        }
    }
}
```

---

## UIKit

You can achieve that similarly in UIKit too:

#### Example

[image: UIKit Demo]

```
    @IBAction func touched(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 3, options: []) {
            self.circleView.transform = .identity
        }
    }

    @IBAction func touchDown(_ sender: Any) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 3, options: []) {
            self.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 240, y: 0)
        }
    }
```